# Which resume to bring when asked to interview for another position

Tags: interviewing, resume

I applied for a position using a resume that is tailored for software development, but was asked to interview for a data analyst position (which I would be happy with).

I have a second version of my resume that is more tailored towards data analyst positions so **which should I bring to the interview**? The original resume, or one more suited to the data analyst position for which I am interviewing?

Comment: Did you already confirm the interview via mail? In a situation like this one thing you could also consider is mailing them the second version when you confirm the interview for that other position.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bring both.

The one you submitted with and the one you think would be most appropriate.

Give the hiring committee a heads up what you are planning though.

Also bring enough copies for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

As Bluebird answered, bring both.

Usually, an interviewer is provided a copy of the resume you submitted (this is not always the case, which is one reason it's generally recommended to bring plenty of copies of your resume).

In this case, you have a resume tailored to the position which is different from the one you submitted. After introductions, I would say something along the lines of, "I have an updated resume that is more tailored to the data analyst position, if you'd like to see it". As I'm saying it, I would present the resume.

Answer (score 0):

You should bring two copies of your resume for the data analyst position because they are hiring for the data analyst position. That way it will be easier for them to ask questions or to interact with you.

I believe you should bring your data analyst resume.